# How to show builtin types using `godoc -http=:6060`?

Tags: go, godoc

If I start

```
godoc -http=:6060
```

and then open `http://localhost:6060/pkg/builtin/#string` (e.g. via a function declaration that uses `string` as a type somewhere), I get a big red "open /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.3.3/libexec/src/builtin: no such file or directory".

How do I get godoc to work the same way as http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#string ?

I tried `go get builtin`, but that did not change anything. And DuckDuckGo and Google searches did not illuminate me either.

(I've installed Go using Homebrew on OS X.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Godoc was updated recently to match the new internal layout of Go 1.4.

Prior to 1.4, system packages went into `$GOROOT/src/pkg/`, in 1.4 (current dev version) they moved to`$GOROOT/src`.

To get the pre-1.4 compatible version:

```
cd $GOPATH/src/code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/godoc
hg checkout -C release-branch.go1.3
go install
```